# Selenium sporadic issues in Chrome probably related to antivirus

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I started to experience sporadic Selenium issues when the new antivirus, Sophos, was installed on the test VM.

E.g. Symptoms are different, e.g. that suddenly only part of the text is entered in the Input Field, then there is a delay from several seconds to several minutes, and rest of the text is entered or the command is failed.

Could be the same freezing on setting a checkbox, clicking on a button, etc.
I changed several Chrome/Selenium versions - it doesn't matter. Only disabling/enabling Antivirus matters.
There wasn't system resource overloading, not even CPU 50% reached.

But I see the next messages in Chrome log every time I spot the issue in UI:

Blockquote

```
[8652:2880:0929/124128.200:VERBOSE1:segment_result_provider.cc(178)] OnGetSegmentInfo: segment=OPTIMIZATION_TARGET_WEB_APP_INSTALLATI
ON_PROMO ignoring DB score, executing model.
[8652:2880:0929/124128.200:VERBOSE1:segment_result_provider.cc(297)] ExecuteModelAndGetScore: segment=OPTIMIZATION_TARGET_WEB_APP_INS
TALLATION_PROMO default segment info not available
[8652:2880:0929/124128.200:VERBOSE1:segment_result_provider.cc(219)] OnGotDatabaseModelScore: segment=OPTIMIZATION_TARGET_WEB_APP_INS
TALLATION_PROMO failed to get database model score, trying default model.
[8652:2880:0929/124128.200:VERBOSE1:segment_result_provider.cc(232)] TryGetScoreFromDefaultModel: segment=OPTIMIZATION_TARGET_WEB_APP
_INSTALLATION_PROMO default provider not available
[8652:2880:0929/124128.200:VERBOSE1:request_dispatcher.cc(143)] Computed result for web_app_installation_promo: Status: Failed
```

I hope it could give a clue to some of you what happened!

What does Chrome do at that moment? E.g., some metrics are written to the disc or user profile is updated, etc...
I can't get rid of the antivirus, but probably some options/exclusions could be tuned on the antivirus side to unblock my automation.

I hope for your help!

Just in case details:

- VM:                             Win server 2016, v1607, Xeon 6126, 4 CPU; 8Gb Ram
- selenium                          4.9.1
- Python 3.10.6, x64
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary    6.1.0
- robotframework                    5.0.1
- Chrome for testing                117.0.5938.62, x64
- ChromeDriver                      117.0.5938.62
- Chrome options    --no-sandbox, --start-maximized, --disable-extensions, --user-data-dir=<my_user>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome for Testing/User Data, --profile-directory=Guest, --v=2
- Sophos Core Agent  2023.1.3.5
- Sophos Intercept X 2023.1.3.5
- Chrome artifacts like folders scoped_dir, chrome_BITS_  are created in  C:\Windows\SystemTemp